# cloth simulation stuck in between two objects

Tags: cloth-simulation

Here is a monkey chef character I made.
This is his elbow.
[image]

I model the basic body then add some extra fur on his elbow.
[image]

Everything was fine when I finish the animation.
I try to add the cloth simulation to him.
The sleeve's cloth stuck between the body and fur.

[image]

[image]

This issue will kill me.

Comment: A cloth simulation with animated characters is very challenging. Do you need this level of realism in your animation? A simpler approach is to run the cloth sim for the posed but not animated character. This way you get the wrinkles and nice appearance of the cloth. Then duplicate the cloth and apply the cloth modifier. Finally, rig the cloth with the character and you can animate it. If needed you can add corrective shapekeys, adjust weights or add helper bones for better deformation.

Comment: Are you simulating the entire shirt or just the sleeves? If it's just the sleeves then it might be easier to archieve whatever you want, but still difficult though because there are many ways it could go wrong during the simulation as you've probably experienced.